# Azure AD B2C login getting error The redirect URI 'localhost:3001' provided in the request is not registered

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I am getting this error on Azure AD B2C login

> AADB2C90006: The redirect URI 'http://localhost:3001/' provided in the request is not registered for the client id '714f2acb-2483-4759-9114-f6c2df737b5d'.

[image]

I have added web redirect url like this:

[image]

following is the react side code

```
import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

export const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: 'B2C_1_signupsignin1',
        forgotPassword: 'B2C_1_reset_v3',
        editProfile: 'B2C_1_editprofile',
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: 'https://testingtenant311.b2clogin.com/testingtenant311.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1',
        },
        forgotPassword: {
            authority: 'https://testingtenant311.b2clogin.com/testingtenant311.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_reset_v3',
        },
        editProfile: {
            authority: 'https://testingtenant311.b2clogin.com/testingtenant311.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_editprofile',
        },
    },
    authorityDomain: 'testingtenant311.b2clogin.com',
};


export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '714f2acb-2483-4759-9114-f6c2df737b5d',
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
        redirectUri: '/',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level: any, message: any, containsPii: any) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        // console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

export const protectedResources = {
    apiTodoList: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:5000/api/todolist',
        scopes: {
            read: ['https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/TodoList/ToDoList.Read'],
            write: ['https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/TodoList/ToDoList.ReadWrite'],
        },
    },
};

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [...protectedResources.apiTodoList.scopes.read],
};
```

Please help me solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also add the code you are trying to implement or the code snippet where you are passing the redirect URL?

Comment: Try to wait for sometime to check if it works or clear the cache

Comment: i added a code also

Comment: What are you passing in redirectUri: '/' parameter in code? try to pass `redirectUri:http://localhost:3001/' `

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/entra-id/app-integration/error-code-AADSTS50011-redirect-uri-mismatch#resolution "Save the changes and wait three to five minutes for the changes to take effect, and then send the login request again" Can you try again?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1306670/azure-ad-b2c-redirect-uri-not-recognising-listed-u

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ***"The redirect URI 'http://localhost:3001/' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'XXX'"*** usually occurs if the redirect URL is not configured in the Azure AD B2C application.

Cross verify whether you have configured the redirect URL in the correct application:

[image]

If still the issue persists, pass the redirect URL in the code too in the **`redirectUri`** parameter:

```js
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'ClientID',
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3001',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    },
```

> **Note** that: After saving the changes or adding the new redirect URL it might take three to five minutes for the changes to take effect. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/entra-id/app-integration/error-code-AADSTS50011-redirect-uri-mismatch#resolution)

- Try to clear the cache and login again.
- Refer this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1306670/azure-ad-b2c-redirect-uri-not-recognising-listed-u) by *Renatas Lauzadis*